# how to merge local folder with git repository?

Tags: git

I have a folder that is linked with GIT to other people. 
However, I copied this folder to make sure I always have a back-up in case merging goes wrong in some way. I accidentally started working on this copied folder though, instead of the one that is connected through GIT. Is there a way to merge this local folder back into the other folder, so I can push my work to remote?

Thanks.

Comment: Are there any changes in the original folder that are not in your backup copy that you accidentally worked in?

Comment: Yes that's the thing, they have pushed to it but I have been working on my own, local version, so they are two different versions and I only got that when pulling the git version and be like: one thing to commit wth?

Comment: Wait wait... how would your co-workers pushing affect your original folder?  While you were in the original folder, did you pull?  Or is your original folder their remote repository?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a `.git` directory in your copied folder? If so - it is just another clone of the git repository, and you can push the changes directly from it.

Or, if you don't have `.git` folder in your copied folder - just copy it here from your original folder.